# Does git-config require explicit folder ownership?

Tags: git, git-config

I have a Bash script that initializes a Git repostitory in an existing, empty directory `storage/`.  The script is executed by a utility user 'gremlin' on an Ubuntu 22.04 system.

The script `cd`'s into `storage/` and runs the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/organization/repo.git .
git config user.name "username"
git config user.email "address"
```

(In practice, "username" and "address" are legitimate options).

I first run the script with the ownership and permissions of `storage/` like this

```
$ ls -Alhd storage
drwxrwxrwx  gizmo gremlin  storage
```

where 'gizmo' is my normal username and both I and 'gremlin' are members of the 'gremlin' group.  Note that 'gremlin' has **full** read, write, and traverse access within `storage/`, exactly the same as the owner 'gizmo'.

When 'gremlin' runs the script, the `git clone` command completes successfully, and the entirety of the contents are owned by `gremlin:gremlin`.  As a sample listing:

```
-rw-rw-r--  gremlin gremlin  build.xml
drwxrwxr-x  gremlin gremlin  .git
```

All files have the exact same ownership and permissions as `build.xml`, and all folders have the exact same ownership and permissions as `.git/`.

Despite the fact that 'gremlin' has full and complete owner-equivalent permissions on both the `storage/` directory and its contents, however, I find that 'gremlin' cannot run the `git config` command within `storage/`:

```
gizmo:/path/to/storage$ sudo -u gremlin git config user.name "username"
fatal: not in a git directory
```

This happens even though the `.git/` folder exists and 'gremlin' has what should be all necessary permissions for altering anything within `storage/`.

I suspect that the `git config` command explicitly checks the user ownership of the directory it's in as part of determining whether it's in a valid Git repository.  To check, I cleared `storage/` and changed its ownership to 'gremlin':

```
$ ls -Alhd storage
drwxrwxrwx  gremlin gremlin  storage
```

Running the script as 'gremlin', both the `git clone` and `git config` commands worked perfectly.  Ownership and permissions on the files and folders withinin the cloned repository did not change between the two tests, which is expected.

So, is this the problem with my script?  Does `git config` explicitly check the ownership of the folder it's being executed in?

I can't find anything from searching for things like "git config folder owner".  The [`git-config` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) are too long to read word-for-word, but a search for "owner" and "permission" doesn't hit on anything relevant.  I also find it curious that it's not a general Git thing; after all, `git-clone` worked fine even though the cloning user does not explicitly own the destination folder.

**EDIT**

I found what I'm looking for, mostly:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.35.2#Documentation/git-config.txt-safedirectory

"By default, Git will refuse to even parse a Git config of a repository owned by someone else."

It isn't fully defined here, but from [other sources](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Exited-with-code-128-saying-fatal-unsafe-repository/qaq-p/2005499), "ownership" does seem to mean user ownership of the directory that contains the `.git/` subfolder.

Comment: Git doesn’t care. Only the OS does.

Comment: @Guildenstern In what sense can the OS care, beyond the ownership and permissions system?

Comment: If `not in a git directory` then Git doesn’t *see* the Git repository as `sudo -u gremlin`; presumably (and hopefully—maybe wishfully) Git would have a better error message if it really *saw* the Git repository but didn’t want `sudo -u gremlin` to do anything with it.

Comment: To test: `sudo -u gremlin pwd`

Comment: @phd `sudo -u gremlin pwd` from within `storage/` works as expected and returns `/path/to/storage`.  What am I testing?

Comment: @Guildenstern Yes, Git appears to recognize the repository only when the user who's looking owns the containing folder outright.  My question is, is this documented Git behavior?

Comment: You don’t have to focus on `git config`. Try `sudo -u gremlin git status` and you will probably get the same error. Try this until you find a Git command with a small enough man page ;)

Comment: Testing that `sudo -u gremlin` executes commands in the proper directory. It does. Now I agree with @Guildenstern: compare `git status` and `sudo -u gremlin git status`.

Comment: I think I always get a similar error when using `etckeeper` in `/etc` since I forget to use `sudo git`.

Comment: The `sudo -u gremlin git status` check gives the `fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository` that's also typically associated with Git being finicky about ownership.

Comment: Okay. Then maybe Git cares after all (revert my first comment). :) That’s a security check from March of last year. Indeed.